# yocto: psplash custom executables do not get installed

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto, bootsplash, bitbake

Depending on the detected hardware I need to start one of two executables of `psplash` with different images, so in my `psplash_%.bbappend` I have

```
SPLASH_IMAGES = "file://bootscreen1.png;outsuffix=type1 \
                 file://bootscreen2.png;outsuffix=type2"
```

And if I `bitbake` it, I find a `psplash-type1` and `psplash-type2` executable in the `tmp/work/.../psplash/build` as well as in `package` and `packages-split` and even in `image`, but it doesn't get included in the final rootfs (there I only find `psplash-write`).

Do I really need to explicitly install the executables, while a `psplash-default` along with the `psplash` link is created automatically and the custom executables are also created magically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out myself and I'll answer it myself, because I couldn't find the answer anywhere in the web:

By giving `outsuffix`es other than `default`, you create separate installables to be included separately in the image recipe

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " \
  psplash \
  psplash-type1 \
  psplash-type2 \
  "
```

This is even an advantage, if you want to have different splashscreens in different images. You just need to know that there is even more magic than you see at the first sight.